# How to combine two separate rows in Bootstrap to a column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following Structure

[image]

I want to push the second row up to the blank area of row 1 using bootstrap. Novice in css please help

**UPDATE**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <form >
SMALL FORM
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
HUGE IMAGE
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    DATA
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have as it is difficult to modify code we can't see.

Comment: @RobAnthony gist of code

Comment: If you put all the `col-*-*` classes in a single row, it'll sometimes work where the content will move up/down based on the other columns, but to truly accomplish this, you'll need something like Masonry or similar. The bootstrap grid system doesn't adapt to vertical space well from my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-12'>
                <form >
                    SMALL FORM
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-12'>
                DATA
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        HUGE IMAGE
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given much to go on, but have you tried the following?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <form >
SMALL FORM
    </form>
    DATA
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
HUGE IMAGE
  </div>
</div>
```